# Flutter Installation Error

Tags: android-studio, flutter

When i try to install Flutter in Android Studio as Plugin i got this error
[image]

But in Flutter Doctor its showing everything is fine

[image]

My pc configuration is i7, 8GB, 1TB, Windows 10

What should i do ?

Comment: Looks like Android studio is pointed to the Zip folder of flutter. Direct it to where you have unzipped the flutter sdk

Comment: error: Fail to load plugin descriptor from file flutter.jar
path is : \flutter_windows_v0.5.1-beta\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android-x86\

Comment: what happens if you try to start a new Android studio project that is based on flutter